# how to add onclick functionality in component

Tags: 9.6

I am using Tridion Site 9.6 as the backend, and Next.js is used for the frontend. I want to add an `onclick` functionality to my anchor tag. We are parsing our component data on the frontend. Is there any way to add an `onclick` event to an anchor tag in Next.js?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion StackExchange, could you please explain bit more detail about your requirement and use case what you are trying to do exactly?